# Why can't I use i++ in for loop in Swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, operators

I know the difference between `i++` and `++i` in *Swift*. As the official document said, it is better to use `++i` to increment `i`.

But I wonder why I get a *syntax error* using `i++` in the *for loop*.
The code looks like this:

```
for var i = 0; i < 10; i++{
    println("hello")
}
```

However, it is OK to use either `i++` or `++i` in other cases. Is there any restrictions in for loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error says that:

> Operator is not a known binary operator

The cause is very simple: you need to add a blank between the operator and the opening curly brace:

```
i++ { 
   ^
```

without that, the compiler takes `++{` as a binary operator, with `i` and `print("hello")` as its arguments

The problem doesn't happen with the prefixed version of the increment operator because the `i` variable makes a clear separation between the `++` operator and the curly brace (letters and numbers cannot be used to define operators).

Comment: @xingyuzhang Glad to know :) Remember to mark the answer as the solution if it actually solved the problem

Comment: As a general rule, Swift requires whitespace around operators where C languages (C, C++, Objective-C) do not. This trips me up sometimes too, and the cryptic error messages you get from Swift make figuring out what's wrong even harder. I'm hoping that as the compiler evolves the errors will get clearer and more helpful.